# Why does my arraylist contain n identical elements when no fields are static?

Tags: java, arraylist, static

I am trying to add objects to an arraylist. None of these objects contain any static fields or static methods, but still when the arraylist is updated, all elements take on the 'new' value. Also, a new instance is created every time I loop, so I do not think that I am adding the same object all the time.

```
ArrayList<Integer> rewards = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
ArrayList<ArrayList<Route>> neighbours = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Route>>();

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    Generate1Neighbour neighbour = new Generate1Neighbour(testDataFile,amp2Solution,randomGenerator,i);
    System.out.println("Generated neighbour (Reward " + getSolutionReward(neighbour.solution)+ "): " + neighbour.solution.toString());
    rewards.add(getSolutionReward(neighbour.solution));
    neighbours.add(neighbour.solution);
}
```

testDataFile and amp2Solution remain unchanged during the loop.

When I print the generated neighbour, I can see that a different neighbour is created in each loop iteration. After this loop, however, neighbours contains 10 identical elements.

Rewards does contain 10 different values.
In the Generate1Neighbour class, no fields or methods are static.

Here, solution is defined as follows:

```
public ArrayList<Route> solution;
```

Within the Generate1Neighbour class, multiple methods are used in which solution is updated.

What can I be doing wrong?

Edit: 
getSolutionReward method is the following:

```
public static int getSolutionReward(ArrayList<Route> solution)
{
    int totalReward = 0;
    for(Route route : solution)
    {
        totalReward += route.getReward();
    }
    return totalReward;
}
```

amp2solution is an ArrayList. In the constructor of Generate1Neighbour, the variable 'solution' is set equal to the amp2solution that was passed to the constructor. This 'solution' variable is updated in numerous methods within the Generate1Neighbour class.

The constructor of Generate1Neighbour is as follows:

```
public Generate1Neighbour(DataFile testDataFile, ArrayList<Route> Sol, Random randomGen, int q_tabu) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Starting Tabu procedure ");
    neighbourhoodSize = "Small";
    solution = Sol;
    S_Comp = new ArrayList<MyNodesData>();
    startPoint = testDataFile.getStartPoint();
    finishPoint = testDataFile.getFinishPoint();
    maxDuration = testDataFile.getMaxDuration();
    randomGenerator = randomGen;
    toRemoveRVI = 3;

    //----------------(A) : Initialization---------------- 
    parameterSet = new ParameterSet(neighbourhoodSize, testDataFile);
    generateSComp(testDataFile, solution, S_Comp);

    //---------Generating neighborhood solutions---------   //Generate number of neighborhood solutions (feasible and 
                                                            //infeasible) to the current solution, based on current
                                                            //tabu parameters.

    routeNumbers = twoRandomTours(solution, randomGenerator);   
    r1 = solution.get(routeNumbers[0]);
    r2 = solution.get(routeNumbers[1]);         

    solution = insertInS(solution, routeNumbers, maxDuration, startPoint, finishPoint, S_Comp, SE, successfulInsert);           
    if(!successfulInsert)
    {
        solution = exchangeWithSComp(solution, parameterSet, routeNumbers, maxDuration, S_Comp, randomGenerator);       
        new RoutesToXLS(solution, "Tabu3");
    }
    else
    {
        new RoutesToXLS(solution, "Tabu2");
    }

    //----------------(B) : Improvement---------------- 

    solution = balance(solution,r1,r2);     
    if(!successfulBalance)
    { 
        exchangeBetweenTours(r1,r2);                    
        new RoutesToXLS(solution, "Tabu5");
    }
    else
    {
        new RoutesToXLS(solution, "Tabu4");
    }
    if(q_tabu % parameterSet.getChi() == 0 && q_tabu!=0)        
    {   
        solution = RVI(solution, routeNumbers, maxDuration, startPoint, finishPoint, S_Comp, SE, randomGenerator, toRemoveRVI, successfulInsert);
        new RoutesToXLS(solution,"AfterRVI");
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you ask exactly that question earlier already? Also your code should work normally.

Comment: Code for this method `getSolutionReward(neighbour.solution)`??

Comment: neighbour.solution is what exaclty? Where does it get created

Comment: @EJP it is stated in the question that `rewards` contains different elements.

Comment: What is `amp2Solution`, and what does the `Generate1Neighbour()` constructor do with it?

Comment: Please provide code of `Generate1Neighbour` class

Comment: @EJP I edited the question, hope this helps!

Comment: @Lino The Generate1Neighbour class consists of over 600 lines of code so I will not be able to provide the full code.

Comment: @YatiSawhney I added the code of the getSolutionReward method

Comment: @Mike Can you at least post the constructor of `Generate1Neighbour`?

Comment: @Lino I added the constructor of `Generate1Neighbour`

Comment: Just as I suspected. You are always using the same `ArrayList<Route>`. You should be copying it in the consutruxtor, instead of just storing a reference.

Comment: @EJP Thanks!! I solved it by making a deep copy of the solution in the constructor. Is there, by any chance, a faster way to do this than by using a deep copy?